# Store variables entered in tkinter form

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a Tkinter-based form where I want to store each item that the user types in as a separate variable. I understand how to generate the form, but I am lost on how to handle the program after the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button. I really just need everything stored as a string.

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

fields = ('Event', 'Event Folder', 'Session', 'Date: (MM/DD/YYYY)', 'StartTime: 24HR(HH:MM)', 'EndTime: 24HR(HH:MM)')

def saveVars(entries):
    locals().update(entries)
    return 

def makeform(root, fields):
   entries = {}
   for field in fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=22, text=field+": ", anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      ent.insert(0,"")
      row.pack(side = TOP, fill = X, padx = 5 , pady = 5)
      lab.pack(side = LEFT)
      ent.pack(side = RIGHT, expand = YES, fill = X)
      entries[field] = ent
   return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   ents = makeform(root, fields)
   b1 = Button(root, text = 'Enter', command = lambda e = ents: saveVars(e))
   b1.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 5)
   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You do not store variables in a command. You run a function from a command and that function then does what you need. IE set a global variable with the string value you want.

Comment: Consider using `StringVar(master)` objects

Comment: Also what is `fetch()` doing?

Comment: Or, maybe, use a `dict` object to store the form data

Comment: Attempted to create a function that takes in the dictionary of entries and turns them into variables.. I simply don't understand how to reference the individual elements of the form and say "var 1 = the entry of box 1"

Comment: @MaxB to reference a single value in a list you use `list_name[index]` so get to get first value it is `list_name[0]` as all list start at index zero. For a dict it is `dict_name[key]` a key can be anything you want but must be unique.

Comment: This question seems all over the place, can you narrow it down? From the comments, you seem to be having issues with the concept of variables and returning values, it's difficult to follow.

Comment: @AMC All I am trying to accomplish is generate a form using tkinter, when the user clicks the `Enter` button or whatever I get a different variable output on my end to play with. Spiraled out of control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is build a function that does something with your entry fields. That said you may want to change up you code a little bit to make this easier. Instead of building your labels and entry fields in a function build them in the global namespace and then store the entry fields in a list.

```
import tkinter as tk

fields = ('Event', 'Event Folder', 'Session', 'Date: (MM/DD/YYYY)',
          'StartTime: 24HR(HH:MM)', 'EndTime: 24HR(HH:MM)')


def do_something_with_entries():
    for ndex, entry in enumerate(entry_list):
        print(fields[ndex], ': ', entry.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    entry_list = []
    for field in fields:
        row = tk.Frame(root)
        lab = tk.Label(row, width=22, text=field + ": ", anchor='w')
        ent = tk.Entry(row)
        entry_list.append(ent)
        row.pack(side='top', fill='x', padx=5, pady=5)
        lab.pack(side='left')
        ent.pack(side='right', expand='yes', fill='x')

    tk.Button(root, text='Enter', command=do_something_with_entries).pack(side='left', padx=5, pady=5)
    root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Here is an example using pandas:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd


fields = ['Event', 'Event Folder', 'Session', 'Date: (MM/DD/YYYY)', 'StartTime: 24HR(HH:MM)', 'EndTime: 24HR(HH:MM)']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=fields)


def do_something_with_entries():
    global df
    stored_values = []
    for ndex, entry in enumerate(entry_list):
        stored_values.append(entry.get())

    series = pd.Series(stored_values, index=fields)
    df = df.append(series, ignore_index=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    entry_list = []
    for field in fields:
        row = tk.Frame(root)
        lab = tk.Label(row, width=22, text=field + ": ", anchor='w')
        ent = tk.Entry(row)
        entry_list.append(ent)
        row.pack(side='top', fill='x', padx=5, pady=5)
        lab.pack(side='left')
        ent.pack(side='right', expand='yes', fill='x')

    tk.Button(root, text='Enter', command=do_something_with_entries).pack(side='left', padx=5, pady=5)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I know this sounds trivial but I am trying to return 6 different variables. I understand how this prints the value that is entered in each one, but how do you generate 6 different variable names and assign each entry to one?

Comment: What do you need names for? If the entry fields are stored in a list you simply need to work with their index. If you can tell me what you need the names for I can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: my approach to getting the individual elements of the list as variables using a function
`def do_something_with_entries():
    a = entry_list[0]
    b = entry_list[1]
    c = entry_list[2]
    d = entry_list[3]
    e = entry_list[4]
    f = entry_list[5]
    return a,b,c,d,e,f`
Doesn't seem to return anything when pressing the button..tkinter stuff just doesn't click for me

Comment: @MaxB `return` will never work with a button. You have no reason to use `return` here. Simply perform the task you need to perform on those values in the function. If you really must have those values stored for later you can just use the loop in the function to store the values to a list. That said the entry list will be usable later so still cannot see a situation where you would need to do something different. Please let me know what you are doing with those values so I can provide an example.

Comment: @MaxB `return` simply sends values to whatever called that function. The problem with tkinter buttons is they ignore returned values. So instead of returning things do something else with them. Return is completely unneeded in this situation. You can do something with those values in many different ways. I need to know the expected end results to provide a clear example.

Comment: My overall goal here was to have each entry returned as an individual variable. I am then going to build a dataframe with 6 different columns, one for each field on the form. I understand how to do all of the pandas side of things, but am woefully incompetent with tkinter.

Comment: All I am trying to accomplish here is have the button close the form, and have 6 different variables available for me to play with.

Comment: @Max: tkinter is what calls the `command` function, and it doesn't care what it returns. As Mike said, you have to do what's needed yourself in the function—and there's no concept of "returning variables" in Python (you can only return values). Although using global variables isn't the best way to program, you could declare `global a,b,c,d,e,f` at the beginning of the function and then assign values to each of them in the lines that follow.

Comment: @martineau My big breakdown here is with tkinter. I simply don't understand buttons. I inserted an `x = entry_list(0)` at the end of the above code as a quick and dirty way to grab the first entry of the list  but when performing `print(x)` after it outputs `.!frame.!entry`.. how is tkinter storing these things

Comment: @MaxB I added a pandas example.

Comment: @MaxB: In Mike's code, tkinter is storing them in `tk.Entry` widgets which are elements of a global list named `entry_list`.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I will do some more reading on the tkinter documents. It just seems not intuitive for me so I have real trouble understanding it!

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the questions as keys and Entry widgets as values of the `entries` dict.

Firstly, put the `entries` dict out of the `makeform` function (otherwise, only makeform function would be able to use it)

Secondly, create the `answer` dict. We are going to store the answers here.

Thirdly, create a `fetch` function which is to be called when the user clicks Enter button. It will go through the `entries` dict and set the values of the `answers` dict to the entered answers (using `Entry.get(...)` method)

Now you can process the form answers.

Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd



fields = ('Event', 'Event Folder', 'Session', 'Date: (MM/DD/YYYY)',
    'StartTime: 24HR(HH:MM)', 'EndTime: 24HR(HH:MM)')
entries = {}
answers = {}

def makeform(root, fields):
   for field in fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=22, text=field + ": ", anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
      entries[field] = ent
   return entries

def fetch():
   for question in entries:
      answers[question] = entries[question].get()
   print(answers) # do something with the results now

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   ents = makeform(root, fields)
   root.bind('<Return>', fetch)
   b1 = Button(root, text='Enter', command=fetch)
   b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   root.mainloop()
```

PS: You don't need to use a `lambda`-function as the button command. Simply use the fetch function as a command.

PS 1: And why do you call `ent.insert(0, "")`? It has no effect.